# On mobile screen sizes, how can I increase the width of a child element while not affecting the size of its sibling?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I expand the width of the text group while not affecting the sizing of the image? When I add a width on the text group, it makes the image smaller.

[image: Result I'm trying to achieve]

```css
body {
  background: #0A0B5B;
}

.hero {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
} 
   
.text-group {
    background-color: green;
}
 
img {
   position: relative;
   right: -40%;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  
  <div class="text-group">
    <h2>Space Enthusiast & JavaScript Developer</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
  </div>

  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamshaunjp/responsive-css-grid-build/lesson-14/assets/banner_image.png" alt="">

</section>
```

Comment: `flex-shrink: 0;` on the text?

Comment: doing that makes the image dissapear @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more suitable for a background:

```css
body {
  background: #0A0B5B;
}

.hero {
  display: flex;
  background: 
    url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamshaunjp/responsive-css-grid-build/lesson-14/assets/banner_image.png) 
    right/
    auto 100% 
    no-repeat;
}

.text-group {
  min-height: 300px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="text-group">
    <h2>Space Enthusiast & JavaScript Developer</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code with more flex configuration. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
body {
  background: #0A0B5B;
}

.hero {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
} 
   
.text-group {
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex: 1 0 500px;
}
 
img {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  
  <div class="text-group">
    <h2>Space Enthusiast & JavaScript Developer</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
  </div>

  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamshaunjp/responsive-css-grid-build/lesson-14/assets/banner_image.png" alt="">

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a fixed `width` and `flex-shrink: 0;` to the `.text-group`. That way it won't become any smaller than the defined width.

```css
body {
  background: #0A0B5B;
}

.hero {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
} 
   
.text-group {
    background-color: green;
    width: 300px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
 
img {
   position: relative;
   right: -40%;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  
  <div class="text-group">
    <h2>Space Enthusiast & JavaScript Developer</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing.</p>
  </div>

  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iamshaunjp/responsive-css-grid-build/lesson-14/assets/banner_image.png" alt="">

</section>
```